# what Kernel Version to Update

Tags: kernel, updates

I have ubuntu 14.04. I want to update kernel, But I do the

`apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, it doesn't change the kernel version, still shows the same kernel version `Linux 3.13.0-121-generic`, but I see a lot of versions. Please explain If I have to update to maintain compliance/ security updates. I thought of downloading the version and do `dpkg`, I need help in deciding what version do I update to and why.

I want to update only the kernel or the security updates, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.13 kernel is still being updated with security patches, which will change the last number (0-121) as new updates are installed.  So it's nothing to worry about.  Ubuntu 14.04 will be supported until April 2019.

You would only need to upgrade the kernel if some newer hardware isn't working on your machine.  However, if you ever did want or need to upgrade the kernel:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```